# ALT+TAB not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have just updated from 18.04 to 20.04. No major issues except that the ALT+TAB (switch between running applications) is not working any more. It simply does nothing

- I have tried two external keyboards and the internal (laptop) one
- the tab button is working
- ALT+"other" is working

Any suggestion?

thanks in advance,
g.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? I have same problem. Keyboard Shortcut's Switch windows is set to Alt+Tab but nothing work, I even press Alt+Tab to change shortcut in this settings. This is really annoying. Alt+Tab is totally not working, it is now as same as Alt only.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look in GNOME Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts. Scroll down and look for "Switch Windows" and see what it's set to.

[image: Keyboard shortcuts panel]

It may be "Disabled". Click the item and you'll be prompted for a keyboard press to set the correct combination. Finally click "Set" to save the choice.

[image: Set shortcut]

Comment: there's a catch with this and it's that there's a delay when you press alt+tab. The famous remove delay extension won't work here

Comment: Interesting. Why would the Ubuntu folks disable the world universal ALT-TAB??? (it was disabled on mine after upgrade 18.04 -> 20.04)