# Can't switch windows nor applications with Alt-Tab after 20.04 Update

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

After the upgrade, my `Alt`+`Tab` / `Alt`+`` ` `` functionality has disappeared. I tried setting it up following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300307/alttab-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033219/alttab-no-longer-switches-applications-since-upgrade-to-18-04), but I don't have a "Switch Window" option in my Keyboard Shortcuts. I tried to set `Alt`+`Tab` to the "Switch applications" or "Switch windows of an app directly", but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Please see this screenshot:

[image: no switch window option]

Anybody could help me bringing this functionality back? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I was using GNOME Compiz. After using the default Ubuntu theme, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use `Alt + Esc`

Somehow maintainers think that this is better. However I always enable `Alt + Tab`

Se this answer: [ALT+Tab no longer switches applications since upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033219/alttab-no-longer-switches-applications-since-upgrade-to-18-04)